# E2U+sip vs sip+E2U

Tags: sip

What is the difference between this two in NAPTR Record?
E2U+sip vs sip+E2U

```
"4.1.6.0.6.5.6.8.8.9.1    IN  NAPTR 102 10 \"u\" \"E2U+sip\" \"!^44(.*)\$!sip:niraj\@userdomain.com!\" .",
"2.4.3.7.2.2.0.4.9.9.1    IN  NAPTR 102 10 \"u\" \"E2U+sip\" \"!^44(.*)\$!sip:nidha\@userdomain.com!\" .",
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, "sip+E2U" was defined in the [RFC2916](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2916.txt)

The order was bad and the newer [RFC3824](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3824) has introduced an update to use "E2U+sip".

This is explained in Section **7.  Compatibility with RFC 2916**

The change was introduced in v3: [diff between v2 and v3 draft for RFC3824](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcdiff?url2=draft-ietf-sipping-e164-03.txt)

As explained in RFC3824, "sip+E2U" should still be supported:

> For backwards compatibility with existing legacy records,
> however, the 'sip+E2U' field SHOULD be supported by an ENUM
> client that support SIP.